# How do I tell what games were recently updated on Steam?

Tags: steam

If you restart steam, your "Downloading" page becomes empty, providing that all the game updates finished and there are no new ones.

How do I find out which games were updated by steam recently? Is there a log or something?

Comment: There isn't a log from my knowledge but you could use the following page to check if your game has been updated:
http://store.steampowered.com/updated/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no way to tell from just the client or the SteamDB trick, since those aren't really helpful in cases where you don't download all the updates, but just some of them. Skip the first part if you just want to get to the answer itself.

### Problems with the solutions of SteamDB and Steam

SteamDB will show **every** update of **all** the games you have. It also doesn't matter whether you downloaded the update or not. This list will probably have Dota2 somewhere in there, if you ever played it. So, this isn't very helpful. I don't want to see all that, just the stuff I downloaded...
Relevant picture:

[image]

Again the Steam's solution is not perfect either, it's better since you can see 20 of the latest updates instead of 10, but if the game didn't publish the update as news, then it doesn't get into this page. Sure, I get a nice list of games but it's not nearly complete and there's stuff I don't want to see there, like the things I didn't download. Relevant picture:

[image]

### Now, the only way I've found that works for me

I just navigate into the Steam's library folder. You can also right click a game and go to Properties -> Local Files -> Browse Local Files then go back one level to the common folder of Steam. If you have more than one library, you **will** need to look at each of them if you want to see all the games, but that's only to make sure you didn't miss anything. Your path will probably look like `X:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common` for extra libraries or `X:\path-to-steam\Steam\steamapps\common` for the main library that Steam keeps inside its folder.

After you got into the folder where all your games are, you just need to sort by latest modified, and "Voila!", you have a whole list of updates that you downloaded in chronological order of the download date instead of the update's date (again, not perfect, but it works way better than the others):

[image]

Comment: Neat trick! Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025187/rules-for-date-modified-of-folders-in-windows-explorer

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh I'm still not sure on this but I think Steam will "touch" the folders (in linux terms) it updates so that they get modified. It might be using this to check for updates (again not sure, but seems like it).

Comment: Will game folders be modified if you play the game? I.e. do some games "touch" the folders when you open them for play and thus throw off the last modified date?

Comment: I think the games usually don't touch the folders themselves, just some files under the folder and it shouldn't mess with the date modified of the folder. Not sure though, there are thousands of games on steam, so it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to see recently updated steam games you own, is [SteamDB - Watching](https://steamdb.info/watching/). You need to login with your steam account. So you will see a list with the last 10 updated games you own, including the timestamp!

Answer (score 1):

[This steam website](http://store.steampowered.com/updated/myapps/) shows all games that recently updated, and your games that were updated aswell, but it only shows the "big" updates, so no small patches.